# Binding rvalue ref to string literal in constructor vs construct in-place

Tags: c++

I'm a bit confused about C++ temporaries in regards to string literals and move semantics.

Which one of the following is better, in terms of performance and readability.

Usage: `Constructor("string_literal")`

Option 1: `s` is created from the string literal, then it is moved into the member variable.

```cpp
Constructor(
   string s
) : s_(std::move(s)) {}
```

Option 2: The string literal is created as a temporary, then bound to `s`, then moved into the member `s_`.

```cpp
Constructor(
   string&& s
) : s_(std::move(s)) {}
```

Option 3: Pass lvalue ref to temporary, then copy-construct `s_`

```cpp
Constructor(
   const string& s
) : s_(s)
```

In the case that caller passes a string literal to the constructor, seems like option 1 is slightly more efficient, since we skip rvalue ref binding and lvalue ref binding, respectively.

If caller passes a string to the constructor, then option 1 will do a copy-and-move, but option 2 forces the user to create a copy, which is then moved. The performance is identical, but the user has a slightly less friendly API for 2.

Which is the best option to go with? Thanks.

Comment: Have a read of [C++ Core Guidelines F.16: For “in” parameters, ...](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-in)

Comment: You could simply add a `const char *` constructor, similar to what `std::basic_string` does.  Then all of those issues you mention become moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 will copy when you have a movable string and construct and move from a literal.

Option 2 will move when you have a movable string and construct and move when you have a literal.

Option 3 is the worst as it will always copy.

As you can see Option 2 <= 1 <= 3.

Also consider

```
Constructor("string_literal"s)
```

This is a `std::string` literal. So Option 2 will just move that right in.

Note: The compiler can optimize copies away as well in many cases.